# How to set the Text of RepositoryItemButtonEdit in layout View in Grid

Tags: devexpress

I create a Grid Control and set Main View as Layout View and add Repository Items is different Columns But When i add Button Edit in Target Column. I want to bind the columns data with the Text property of Button. Plzzzzzzz am too worried about it. tell me any Solution about that How to set the Text of RepositoryItemButtonEdit in layout View in Grid

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the event that happens when an editor is about to be shown in a non-focused mode `CustomRowCellEdit`.

```
private
void gridView_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column != columnWithButtonEdits) {
        BusinessObject obj = (BusinessObject) gridView.GetRow(e.RowHandle);
        e.RepositoryItem.Buttons[0].Text = obj.SomeProperty;                
    }
}
```

Of course you have to cast `RepositoryItem` to your type and get the button that you need.